# Amazon S3 png files don't have transparency

Tags: php, zend-framework, amazon-s3, gd

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but PNG files uploaded to an S3 Amazon bucket show a white color instead of transparent, even though the local file does show transparency. Here is what I have:

```
$thumb = \PhpThumbFactory::create(
  $content,
  array(
    'jpegQuality' => 100
  ),
  true
);

$thumb->setFormat('PNG');

ob_start();
$thumb->show(true);
$content = ob_get_clean();

//This part is for testing purposes, I store the file locally to see that the transparency is there
$file = 'picture' . '-' . time() . '.png';
file_put_contents($file, $content); //The file created is an image which perfectly shows the transparent, as it should be

//The code below should upload the same file, but somehow it replaces transparency with a white color. 
$S3 = new Zend_Service_Amazon_S3($myKey, $mySecret);
$response = $S3->putObject(
  $bucket,
  $content,
  array(
    Zend_Service_Amazon_S3::S3_CONTENT_TYPE_HEADER => 'image/png',
    Zend_Service_Amazon_S3::S3_ACL_HEADER => Zend_Service_Amazon_S3::S3_ACL_PUBLIC_READ
  )
);
```

Am I missing something when doing the upload? Is there anything that I should configure on the bucket?

Comment: looks like your creating the thumbnail as a jpg first so its stripping out the transparency, nothing wrong with amazon s3

Comment: Like I said, I'm saving the file locally right before that, and the local file has transparency.

Comment: I promise you it's not an amazon issue, they don't change the files you upload, it's your code ;-)

Comment: We had a similar problem, and defining Content-Length explicitly solved the issue. also look at:   

https://github.com/SmileyChris/easy-thumbnails/issues/337

They had a similar issue. Didn't delve in, but it seems there is a way to force S3 to keep transparency.